# IPTables Range of Ports

Tags: iptables, centos6, linux-networking

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20000:25000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 20004 -j ACCEPT
```

Those are my two rules I made in my iptables in an attempt to open up all the ports from 20000:25000 when I realized the first didn't work I tried just an individual port, but still not open, the ports are being used for Minecraft and so with iptables on I can't connect to the servers, with them off, I can connect to the Minecraft servers no problem.

Yes I have been restarting my iptables each time and I'm on CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIR, CentOS uses predefined firewall rule set, so you either need to fit just into it, or at least try inserting those rules at the very beginning of the list (`iptables -I INPUT 1`)

Comment: Fixed it!

I added

    -F INPUT

On the line right above it! THanks guys! @poige was on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow also the following traffic:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This is important to allow the traffic coming back as reply. Otherwise, the connection can be fully established. Of course, this is assuming default `DROP` policy for `INPUT`.

Comment: Khaled, I think its worth mentioning the method to your madness regarding the use of just NEW vs. NEW, RELATED, and ESTABLISHED